# android ObjectGraph in new version of Dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2

i'm trying to update this below code to dagger2, but i get error for `ObjectGraph`:

```
import dagger.ObjectGraph;
public class App extends Application {
    private static App instance;
    private ObjectGraph objectGraph;
    public App() {
        instance = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new AppModule());
    }

    public static void injectMembers(Object object) {
        getInstance().objectGraph.inject(object);
    }

    public static <T>T get(Class<T> klass) {
        return getInstance().objectGraph.get(klass);
    }

    public static App getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

how can i update that to and which class must be use instead of `ObjectGraph`?

`injectMembers` used in this class

```
public class MyJobManager extends JobManager {
    public MyJobManager(Context context) {
        super(context, new Configuration.Builder(context)
                .injector(new DependencyInjector() {
                    @Override
                    public void inject(BaseJob baseJob) {
                        App.injectMembers(baseJob);
                    }
                })
 .build());
    }
}
```

now how can i inject with component?

my component:

```
@ActivitiesScope
@Component(dependencies = GithubApplicationComponent.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(ActivityRegister activityRegister);

    void inject(ActivityStartUpApplication activityStartUpApplication);

    void inject(GetLatestRepositories getLatestRepositories);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dagger 2 doesn't use an ObjectGraph.  It doesn't use anything as its replacement.  Dagger1 did injection at runtime via reflection and used the ObjectGraph to provide that functionality.  Dagger 2 does injection at compile time, thus it doesn't need a runtime object to represent the graph.  Instead you'd want to build a component that links the modules you with to provide.  You can then inject using that component.

See https://google.github.io/dagger/dagger-1-migration.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks, my post updated sir, could you please review that?

Comment: So I dagger 2, you only need to manually inject objects created by the android framework. Everything else should be injected via constructor. To inject the items made by the framework, you create a component as discussed, then add an inject method that takes an instance of the object you wish to inject in it. Then you instantiate the component at runtime and call that function

Comment: its very hard for me to understand, could you show me on code how can i do that? please